# Why does a ChromeWorker throw "Components is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul

The [documentation on ChromeWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/ChromeWorker) says that they have "chrome privileges", and [chrome privileges are supposed to mean they can do anything](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome), but when I create a ChromeWorker and try to use `Components` I get an error that 'Components' is not defined..

So my question is

1. why is Components not available?
2. what is available to a ChromeWorker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access the `Components` object because the `Components` object isn't threadsafe.  A ChromeWorker gives you [access to everything a Worker has access to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Worker), and c-types.